# Detecting Invalid Resource sections in PE FIles

Tags: windows, x86, disassembly, portable-executable

I am trying to perform certain calculations using the resources in a PE File. To do so I follow these steps:

1. Get the RVA of Resource Section from the header

   PEHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].VirtualAddress
2. Convert the above RVA to File Offset
3. Reach to the start of Resource Section and traverse the resource tree
4. Reach the leaves (actual resources) and do the calculations.

The above steps work just fine when I am dealing with proper PE Files with valid resource sections but I am unable to handle the following cases:

- The RVA of Resource Section is present in DataDirectory but the actual ".rsrc" section is missing
- The ".rsrc" section is present but without section header
- The ".rsrc" section is present but it's header has garbage values in either PointerToRawData or SizeOfRawData field.
- I encounter a garbage value in fields such as OffsetToData/OffsetToDirectory midway while traversing the resource tree

When met with the above situations, my code crashes with ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTIONS or produces inconsistent results.

My question is that apart from checking for NULL pointers/values, how do I handle the above cases when the resource section headers and pointers are pointing to/containing something junk.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C++, so I removed C++ tag. May be some other tags are in order, but C++ is not one of them.

Comment: Please post code. The .RSRC name shouldn't mean anything, only the section referenced by PEHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE]. Always range-check everything the PE file references at the minimum to be within the file. The more you know about the target, the more you can constrain the range-check. I.e. Range check any RVAs against the limits of the virtual image size (memory) before referencing them.  NOTE: OffsetToData sets the uppermost bit (IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_IS_DIRECTORY) if the value is a directory pointer.  Without masking this off, the pointer will be invalid.